# PyQt4: Display progress bar while qtsql table is being loaded

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtsql

Is it possible to get the number of records in a table after `QtSql.QSqlTableModel.setTable(tableName)` and before `QtSql.QSqlTableModel.select()`?
Qt documentation about **setTable** function says:

> *Sets the database table on which the model operates to tableName. Does not select data from the table, but fetches its field information.*

So these are my questions :) Which field information? Does it contain the number of records? How to access it if necessary? (I would like to display a progress bar while the table is being loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `setTable` you can get the number of fields, field names and the number of records of your table via `QSqlQuery` objects by issuing `SQL` commands, for instance:

```
model = QSqlTableModel(db=your_db)
model.setTable("your_table")
...
query = QSqlQuery("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='your_table'")
query.next()
print query.numRowsAffected() # print the number of fields
query.previous()
while query.next():
    print query.value(0).toString()  # print the field name
```

will print the number of fields the table "your_table" and the field names.

For getting the number of rows without populating your model you can use a  `COUNT` command as follows:

```
query = QSqlQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table")
query.next()
print query.value(0).toString()  # print the number of records
print model.rowCount()  # print 0 as the model has not been populated yet
```

I thought that `COUNT(1)` performs better than `COUNT(*)` but it seems to be a myth (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)).

Comment: @Vincent thanks! do you know how long will it take to calculate the number of rows though? if it takes as much as populating the table it might be quite inefficient...

Comment: No, I don't know how to do this calculation.